# Question asked 1 year ago being shown in `last 7 days` in achievements drop menu

Tags: support

I asked the following question one year ago

[I can't help coding](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/41030/9521)

In my account on achievements button [image: achievements button], when I click it this question is shown in last 7 days section.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working correctly.  It's based on when you received the reputation, not when the question is posted.

You received an upvote 5 days ago.  That's within the last 7 days, so that's where it shows up under achievements.